# Visual Studio 2015 Integration Services project does not pick up my custom SSIS component

Tags: ssis

My development environment: SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio 2015,  [SQL Server Data Tools Preview (September) for Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383)

I have a custom SSIS source component that I can successfully use on another SQL 2014 box with  [VS 2013 and SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383). However, this component does not show up in the toolbox in VS 2015 Integration Services project.

The component is located in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents. It is also registered in GAC.

Do I need to make changes to the component so that it will work with VS2015? 
More general question: how to troubleshoot issues like this?

Comment: Of course it doesn't. VS 2010, VS 2012 = SQL Server 2012. VS 2013 = SQL Server 2014. VS 2015 = SQL Server 2016 (once it's RTMed)

Comment: I was able to use VS 2015 (SQL Server Data Tools Preview) to create projects against SQL Server 2014. The part that does not work (which is the core of my question) is that I can't get VS 2015 to pick up my custom source component. I suspect, there must be some changes that I need to make on the custom component.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Custom components won't show up in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the problem of adding a custom SSIS component to a Visual Studio 2015 SSIS package. This maybe have been enabled by the release of SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.2, but I thought that I'd put this out there in case it helps anyone.

First of all let me just let everyone know what system I'm using in case this doesn't work for everyone:

My system is: Windows 8.1 64 bit

Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 13.0.900.80 (I've installed the SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2 so the version of SSIS is this version - this may be part of the problem and it isn't a fully released product and this may be a bug)

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055

In my c# class project I used the .NET Framework 4.6 
(Project Properties->Application).

I made sure that I added to the gac using the gacutil.exe in the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools

and I copied the dll to the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\PipelineComponents

After refreshing the SSIS toolbox the component now appears in the Common folder/subsection.

I hope this works for everyone or is at least of use to anyone else who has had this problem. I was so happy after trying nearly everything and it coming up blank to see the component appear in the SSIS toolbox and know how frustrating this kind of thing can be!!!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015 Solution Explorer, right click on the .dtproj file and select properties. On the General Tab choose the SQL Server version that matches the component version. If the component worked on VS2013, choose 'SQL SERVER 14' when opening the package in VS2015.